# Solr Data Import Scheduling from MySQL

Tags: solr, scheduling, dataimporthandler

I am a newbie to Solr, I m trying to schedule an import from MySQL to Solr.
The full-import functionality is working fine when I my trying to import data from Solr admin, but when I am trying to configure the data-import through the documentation provided on [apache site](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Scheduling), I am not able to move forward.

Just after adding the listener to solr web.xml file, my solr is going down and not coming up. Also as mentioned in the documentation there should be `dataimport.properties` file on `solr.home/conf/` path. But I don't have that path also for my solr4.1

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of the scheduling component.
Take a look here for more info: https://github.com/mbonaci/solr-data-import-scheduler

Comment: I did try to follow all the instructions from that link, but as mentioned earlier, I am not able to find conf folder inside solr.home, instead conf folders are there inside the respective core folders. Any kind of pointers would be really appreciated.

Comment: Yes, that's back from v3 and I haven't updated it for more recent versions. So I suggest that you setup example DIH that comes with Solr, using bin/solr -e dih, as described here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler and then you see where the conf dir will end up and go from there.

Comment: Thanks Marko, I will surely check for same.

Comment: Then, when you find the exact procedure, please report back here or on GitHub, so other users of newer versions of Solr can benefit. Thanks

Comment: Sure Marko I will do it !!